# How to apply a function to a dictionary within a file?

Tags: python

So I have this function (invert_dict) which inverts dictionaries:

```
def invert_dict(d):
    inverse = dict()
    for key in d:
        val = d[key]
        for ele in val:
            if ele not in inverse:
                inverse[ele] = [key]
            else:
                inverse[ele].append(key)
    return inverse
```

This is my dictionary which is stored in a file called Dict.py

```
Dictionary = {
    'Student1': 'Sally',
    'Student2': 'Hannah',
    'Student3': 'Ahmed',
    'Student4': 'Talia',
    'Student5': 'Cassia',
    'Student6': 'Talal',
    'Student7': 'Mawahib',
    'Student8': 'Nadia',
    'Student9': 'Nala',
    'Student10': 'Alyssa'
}
```

My task is to apply the function to this dictionary after pulling it from its file. The later steps I can take care of my assignment. I'm just stuck on how to apply the function to the file I tried:

```
with open('Dict.py') as rf: 
    result_1 = invert_dict(rf)
    print (result_1)
```

However, it didn't work.

I tried:

```
with open('Dict.py') as rf: 
    result_1 = invert_dict(rf)
    print (result_1)
```

I was expecting to get this output:

```
{'S': ['Student1'], 'a': ['Student1', 'Student2', 'Student2', 'Student4', 'Student4', 'Student5', 'Student5', 'Student6', 'Student6', 'Student7', 'Student7', 'Student8', 'Student8', 'Student9', 'Student9', 'Student10'], 'l': ['Student1', 'Student1', 'Student4', 'Student6', 'Student6', 'Student9', 'Student10'], 'y': ['Student1', 'Student10'], 'H': ['Student2'], 'n': ['Student2', 'Student2'], 'h': ['Student2', 'Student3', 'Student7'], 'A': ['Student3', 'Student10'], 'm': ['Student3'], 'e': ['Student3'], 'd': ['Student3', 'Student8'], 'T': ['Student4', 'Student6'], 'i': ['Student4', 'Student5', 'Student7', 'Student8'], 'C': ['Student5'], 's': ['Student5', 'Student5', 'Student10', 'Student10'], 'M': ['Student7'], 'w': ['Student7'], 'b': ['Student7'], 'N': ['Student8', 'Student9']}
```

Instead, I got an error: `[Program finished]`

Comment: import it... do `from Dict import Dictionary`  then you just apply the function to the dictionary variable then `invert_dict(Dictionary)`  done... just make sure the file is located in an importable location

Comment: Can you explain why you saved your `Dictionary variable` in a `.py` file? Why not a simple `.txt' file or `.json` file?

Comment: No particular reason. I can change it to a .txt if that makes it easier to handle